# Best way to add a prefix to a react-select box

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm working with `react-select` and was wondering how I can get the component to prefix the selected label with `Show:` or any other copy I'd like? I'd prefer to bake this into the component rather than change the labels. Hopefully this is possible.

Bonus question: how can I easily remove the left border line on the `DropdownIndicator`. It doesn't seem to be apart of the indicator at all.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override every [sub-components](https://react-select.com/components) of `Select` to change the behavior of the components. In your case, prefix the selected value with whatever you want. Here's a small example to get your started.

If you want to remove the `IndicatorSeparator` component, simply create a corresponding component that returns `null`

```js
const VALUE_PREFIX = "Show: ";

export default function MySelect() {
  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      placeholder="All"
      components={{
        SingleValue: ({ children, ...props }) => {
          return (
            <components.SingleValue {...props}>
              {VALUE_PREFIX + children}
            </components.SingleValue>
          );
        },
        Placeholder: ({ children, ...props }) => {
          return (
            <components.Placeholder {...props}>
              {VALUE_PREFIX + children}
            </components.Placeholder>
          );
        },
        IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64014975/best-way-to-add-a-prefix-to-a-react-select-box]

Comment: Thanks! Where was this detail documented? Unless I read the source for this I wouldn't even know where to start looking...which for a select component is *far* too much effort. Also the documentation you linked doesn't nearly do enough to explain what those sub-components are, do or how they work. Just my experience. Thanks for your support though.

Comment: @ddibiase, you can print the `props` of the components to study how the components work or just open the [react devtool](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html) to inspect every components's props and state you want. I only go to the docs to get a quick look at which component I can modify. At least that's my method.